Image Classification Wizard: Error Message
After classifying the image into impervious/ pervious surface areas and applying a supervised classification of the different features, I tried to run the Image Classification Wizard. This is the error message I received:
Failed to read a pixel block.
 [IRasterCursor::Next()]
Function Read Error [Raster Function Template]
Function Read Error [Rendered Raster Function]
Function Read Error [Extract Bands]
Failed to read a pixel block.
Expected to find comma, colon or start of array; state : Empty; buffer : <CIMRasterRGBColorizer xsi:type='typens:CIMRasterR
Distributing operation across 6 parallel instances.
 [IRasterCursor::Next()]
Function Read Error [Raster Function Template]
Function Read Error [Rendered Raster Function]
Function Read Error [Extract Bands]
Failed to read a pixel block.
 [IRasterCursor::Next()]
Function Read Error [Raster Function Template]
Function Read Error [Rendered Raster Function]
Function Read Error [Extract Bands]
Failed to read a pixel block.
Expected to find comma, colon or start of array; state : Empty; buffer : <CIMRasterRGBColorizer xsi:type='typens:CIMRasterR
Failed to execute (SegmentMeanShift).
Failed at Sunday, June 9, 2024 3:50:10 PM (Elapsed Time: 19 minutes 58 seconds)

Does this provide any insight into why it didn't work?
I'm using ArcGIS Pro 3.2, and a near map imagery for my raster layer.
